# Unexpected horizontal alignment when using enumitem

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, indentation, enumitem

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[
  label = \arabic*),
  itemindent = *
]
  \item before
  \begin{equation*}
    A
  \end{equation*}
  after
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Why are `before` and `after` not horizontically aligned and how do I get the alignment?

Comment: Put `itemindent = !` or remove that line totally.

Comment: Why no use `leftmargin=*` instead of `itemindent=*`?

Comment: Or `itemindent = 0pt`.

Comment: @cfr `itemindent=0pt` leaves the *items* a litte separated of the margin and keeps `leftmargin`. Use `showframe` package to see this.

Comment: @skpblack What is `showframe` supposed to demonstrate? Maybe I just didn't understand the question properly but I didn't think the issue was separation from the margin at all.

Comment: @cfr what I mean is that `itemindent=0pt` doesn't seem to have some effect. It's preferable not to put it

Comment: @skpblack I don't understand. Your suggestion kills the indentation of the item altogether i.e. `1` is flush against the left margin. But that is not what the question asked, as I understand it. The issue was the alignment of `before` and `after`. When I use `itemsep=0pt`, those are aligned without altering the indentation of the item as a whole. Of course, if you don't want the list to be indented, that's a different matter. But that's not how I understood the question.

Comment: Just remove the setting of `itemindent` altogether...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it suffices to remove any specification of `itemindent`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label = {\arabic*)}]
  \item before
  \begin{equation*}
    A
  \end{equation*}
  after
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on _why_ `itemindent` is not nessecary (and why you put curly brackets around `\arabic*)`)?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: The curly braces is purely habit. Not setting `itemindent` means it retains it's default value, resulting in a non-hanging-indent or horizontally-flush view (since the label is set in a `\llap`-fashion. [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s use of `*` or `!` is sometimes confusing for me too...